# How do I get the server name in Django for a complete url?

Tags: django-templates

I'm using django templates to create an e-mail. I do something like this:

```
msg_html = render_to_string('email/%s.html' % template_name, context)
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, msg_text, from_email, to_list)
msg.attach_alternative(msg_html, "text/html")
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

My template uses named url patterns like so:
    {% url url_name parameter %}

Which works fine, except it will render a relative url, like: 
    /app_name/url_node/parameter

Usually that is enough, but since this is an e-mail I really need it to be a full url - with the server name prepended, like: 
    http://localhost:8000/app_name/url_node/parameter.

How can I do this? How do I dynamically get the server name? (I don't want to hardcode it for sure).

Another way of asking:  how do I get HttpServletRequest.getContextPath() ala Java, but instead in Django/Python?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use sites application:

```
Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

Example direct from documentation:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def register_for_newsletter(request):
    # Check form values, etc., and subscribe the user.
    # ...

    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    send_mail('Thanks for subscribing to %s alerts' % current_site.name,
        'Thanks for your subscription. We appreciate it.\n\n-The %s team.' % current_site.name,
        'editor@%s' % current_site.domain,
        [user.email])

    # ...
```

Comment: How about WITHOUT using Sites? Is there a way to do this? It's pretty silly to have to rely on a model.

Comment: You could always set it in your settings file and over-ride it with your local_settings file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django