# django full url in get_absolute_url

Tags: django

I want to have a absolute/complete url when i call my models get_absolute_url method in template. in my entry model i have below:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('blog_entry_detail', (), { 'year': self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
                                           'month': self.pub_date.strftime("%b").lower(),
                                           'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"),
                                           'slug': self.slug })

get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

in my template file:

```
{{object.get_absolute_url}}
```

I want to output the url prepended with 'http://www.example.com'

I want to use below lines to get the current domain name but i dont know where will i put it.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
current_site = Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

Comment: There's a good answer to this question here, which you might adapt to provide a method on your model (note that you might need to pass the request object to the template as extra context): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        path = reverse('display_article', args=[self.slug])
        return "http://%s%s" % (self.site, path)
```

Comment: Still sucks that it doesn't auto-detect the protocol for you. You'd think at least the RequestSite object would know that!

Comment: How are you dealing with `port` ? Development server run on 8000 (default, but you might set another one), as production runs probably default  80 or 443 (and unmentioned in URL).

Comment: `self` does not have `site` now! Django 2.1

Answer (score 3):

My solution, with *Sites framework*

In **API\views.py**

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    absolute_url = serializers.CharField(source='get_full_absolute_url', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = ( 'id', 'created_at', 'msg_txt', 'url', 'absolute_url' )
```

In **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Notification(models.Model):
    sender_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'sender_user' )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    reciever_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'reciever_user')
    readed_at = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, null = True )
    msg_txt = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/notification/%i/" % self.id

    def get_full_absolute_url(self):
        domain=Site.objects.get_current().domain

        return 'http://%s%s' % (domain, self.get_absolute_url())
```

**Var 2, without Sites framework**

If you have not Sites framework, you can use the ALLOWED_HOSTS settings.

In **models.py**

```
from myapp.settings import ALLOWED_HOSTS

class Notification(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_full_absolute_url(self):
        domain=ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]

        return 'http://%s%s' % (domain, self.get_absolute_url())
```

[ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) is required for production site.

Comment: How to deal with `port` ? Development server run on 8000 (default, but you might run it over another one), as production runs probably default (and unmentioned in URL) 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1):

When I need full URLs, I usally go for `request.get_absolute_url()`, rather than assemble it myself using `Site.objects.get_current().domain`. However, there seem to be some [issues](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ReplacingGetAbsoluteUrl) with this method.

In any case, I don't think the model is the right place to put this because it violates the DRY principle by duplicating the URL in the urlconf and in the model. Can you not use some form of [reverse URL lookups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)?

Comment: can you pls give some example on how to use request.get_absolute_url()? currently i have a context processor to pass the site name variable to templates and assemble the absolute url like this:
<a href="{{SITE_DOMAIN}}{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{object.title}}</a>
which i think is not a good way to output the absolute url

Comment: Just pass the URL relative to your root URL confirm like 'request.get_full_url(URL_to_my_view)'. I often use that along with the reverse lookup, which is also why I links to that.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find any up-to-date answer on this, I achieved the results by this:

In settings.py, I set `BASE_URL` and then in models `get_absolute_url` method:

```py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.conf import settings
    path = reverse('urlname', args=(arg)) # Assuming that a URL with name `urlname` is set in urls.py
    return '{}{}'.format(settings.BASE_URL, path)
```

I don't know either this is the best way to get the full URL or not, but I didn't find any better way to achieve the desired results. I hope this helps someone.