# Django Get Absolute URL

Tags: django, url, absolute

I want to get absolute url in templates. I can't do with url. It gives me a relative URL. I need to get this:

```
http://domain.tld/article/post
```

but Django gives me just

```
/article/post
```

I played with settings.py but it didn't work. (debug=false, allowed hosts vs.)

Template code:

```
{% url 'blog:detail' blog.slug %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [django full url in get\_absolute\_url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994060/django-full-url-in-get-absolute-url)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri This might help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a long time meeting with Django, I learned a lot of things. For this issue, I created an absolute URL templatetag.

Add this to your template tags, then use like default url tag:

`{% absurl 'some-view' with, arguments %}`

[Here is the Gist for the absolute URL templatetag](https://gist.github.com/laxxxguy/69aec1259131b5619fb7), you will need to add request object to template_context_processors, otherwise this will not work. To achieve this, open your settings.py and add these following lines:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Comment: You may also need to load the template tag, e.g. assuming the file is named `absurl.py` then you'd add `{% load absurl %}` to the top of your template

Comment: Neat solution, thanks. Remember to restart django dev server to load the newly added templatetag.

Answer (score 31):

This is easy to do in a view. For example:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def Home(request): 
    posts = Article.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-publish') 
    site = Site.objects.get_current()

    c = RequestContext(request, { 
        'posts': [{'post': post,
                   'url': request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('blog:detail', args=[post.slug]))}
                  for post in posts]
        'site': site,
    }) 

    return render_to_response('templates/index.html', c)
```

Then, in your template, while you're looping with `{% for postobj in posts %}` you can access `postobj.post` and `postobj.url`.

If you want to do this in the template instead you can probably create your own template tag without too much trouble.

Comment: Where to place it? I added the views and models to question. Can you help me please? I'm working it for 2 days :S And I'm using it in for loop.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer with a code example based on your views.py. Some other notes: `filter()` doesn't raise a `DoesNotExist` exception, it just returns an empty list; but `get()` _does_ raise a `DoesNotExist` exception so you should check for it in your `Detail` view.