# Python, Django 1.7 : Redirect all URLs to a single controller

Tags: python, regex, django, url, model-view-controller

let's base URL is `so.com` 
So, if URL start with abc e.g.

```
so.com/abc/
so.com/abc/123
so.com/abc?newtab=123
so.com/abc#123
so.com/abc/123?tab=new
...
```

Then all this URL patterns should go to a Class Abc

```
myapp/urls.py 
...
url(r'^abc[a-zA-Z0-9=#_\?\-/]+$',views.Abc.as_view(),name='abc')
```

myapp/myviews/abc.py

```
class Abc(View):
   def get(self,request):
    ...
   def foo(user_id):
   ...
   def bar(post_id):
   ...
```

In function `get(self,request):` how to get everything after abc  that  was requested .
e.g.

```
so.com/abc/xyz => /xyz
so.com/abc#123 => 123
so.com/abc?tab=new => ?tab=new 
 so.com/abc/123?tab=new => tab = new and 123
```

When `#123` is added after abc then it automatic converts to `abc/#123`

How to get this work ?

I have seen many question but they are not helpful.

[Django Get Absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866114/django-get-absolute-url)

[What is a "slug" in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django)

[How to get the current URL within a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template)

...

Answer (score 1):

So, first, you cant get `#` parameter.That is not sent to the server, read more [here](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html)

To parse `so.com/abc/xyz => /xyz` and `so.com/abc?tab=new => ?tab=new`

```
url(r'^abc/?$',views.Abc.as_view(),name='abc')
url(r'^abc/(?P<param>\w+)/?$',views.Abc.as_view(),name='abc')

class Abc(View):

    def get(self,request,param=None):
        print param # in param you get /xyz
        tab = request.GET["tab"] # here you get ?tab=new
```

Comment: did you check ? on my system so.com/abc/xyz  print None .

Comment: It still gives None .

Comment: In that case url `so.com/abc/` can not be parsed .

Comment: @sonukumar yes, just add `/?`

Comment: It still wrongs you there is optional  ` (?P<param>\w+)`  so  you have to add `?` after this

Comment: @sonukumar u can add another url rule, check it.

Comment: I know regular expressions . Only thing that i didn't know how to retrieve values from this .

Comment: Do we have any method to directly called a controller with an parameter like `Codeigniter`  where a controller function can be directly invoked from URL .