# How to get a string representation of a URL full path in Django?

Tags: python, django, url

I'm trying to send a URL to an external website as a callback and I'm wondering if there is a way to pass the URL name from `urlpatterns` and required arguments.

The solution would return the full path of the URL as a string instead of hardcoding it.

The URL in `urls.py` looks something like this:

```
app_name = example_app
urlpatterns  = [
                ...
                '<int:example_id>/, views.my_function, name='some_name'
               ]
```

And I would like the URL to be something like this, where `1` is an `example_id`:

```
 https://my_site_domain.com/example/1/
```

Comment: You can get 'example/1/' from the named URL and for this 'https://my_site_domain.com/' you can use the hardcoded settings variable DOMAIN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866114/django-get-absolute-url Maybe this will help you