# Django: Getting the full URL of the current request

Tags: python, django, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

When I use `request.get_full_path()`, I get something like

```
/whatever/path?with=get_too
```

But I don't get the hostname! I want to get the full URL in order to redirect back to this page from an external page.

Now, I could try something like `'%s%s' % (request.get_host(), request.get_full_path())`, but if there's something ready-made, that would be better, because then I'd be sure that all the quirks have been worked out of it.

Is there one?

Comment: Agreed. [These characters added to appease StackOverflow's weird rules.]