# Django get the static files URL in view

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I'm using reportlab pdfgen to create a PDF. In the PDF there is an image created by `drawImage`. For this I either need the URL to an image or the path to an image in the view. I managed to build the URL but how would I get the local path to the image?

How I get the URL:

```
prefix = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
image_url = prefix + request.get_host() + STATIC_URL + "images/logo_80.png"
```

Answer (score 341, accepted):

```py
# Older Django <3.0 (also deprecated in 2.0):
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

# Django 3.0+
from django.templatetags.static import static

url = static('x.jpg')
```

url now contains `'/static/x.jpg'`, assuming a static path of `'/static/'`

Comment: Do you know if there's a clean way of adding the hostname to the static url (if not present in STATIC_URL)?
I need to add images or other resources in mails, where the user won't be able to find the resources with relative urls.

Comment: This does not work for me while running in Debug (haven't tried yet with DEBUG=False).  I simply get the path passed into the static method returned.  Using Django 1.6.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the code using django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles should be prefered taking into account that is compatible with django-storages and similar.

Comment: @gepatino You can route the result through `request.build_absolute_uri` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django

Comment: For anyone having the same problem as @Shawn (or me), this could be because you are giving a path that starts with a slash. Don't do `static('/style.css')`, do instead `static('style.css')`.

Comment: In Django 2.0, this will show a deprecation notice. Use `from django.templatetags.static import static` instead.

Comment: In Django 2.0.1 server logs, I am getting a `No such file or directory: '/static/my_file_name.xlsx'` whereas I can see the file if I access the URL directly from the browser `localhost:8080/static/my_file_name.xlsx`

Comment: @Anupam you probably added `'/static'` to your argument to the `static` function, which isn't right. Try `static('my_file_name.xlsx')`.

Comment: I get **[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static'**

Comment: I got this error when I tried to use it inside settings.py: 
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 94):

EDIT: If you're on Django >=3.0, refer to [Django get the static files URL in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view/59355195#59355195) instead. This was answered with Django 1.X version.

dyve's answer is good one, however, if you're using "cached storage" on your django project and final url paths of the static files should get "hashed"(such as *style.aaddd9d8d8d7.css* from *style.css*), then you can't get a precise url with `django.templatetags.static.static()`. Instead, you must use template tag from `django.contrib.staticfiles` to get hashed url.

Additionally, in case of using development server, this template tag method returns non-hashed url, so you can use this code regardless of that the host it is development or production! :)

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

# 'css/style.css' file should exist in static path. otherwise, error will occur 
url = static('css/style.css')
```

Comment: Thanks for this... took me a while to figure out why I wasn't getting my md5 hashes injected

Comment: This answer is still getting hits and is actively used, so I improved my accepted answer with credits to @Kenial. This is still the preferred solution for this problem.

Comment: In Django 3.2, there is no templatetags in django.contrib.staticfiles. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59355195

Comment: @dfrankow seemed I made this answer in the somewhere of Django 1.3... wow it has been a while. Thanks for enhancing it up!

Answer (score 36):

From Django 3.0 you should use `from django.templatetags.static import static`:

```py
from django.templatetags.static import static

...

img_url = static('images/logo_80.png')
```

Comment: And then in your template use ```<img src="{{img_url}}" alt="img_url">```

Answer (score 16):

here's another way!  (tested on Django 1.6)

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
staticfiles_storage.url(path)
```

Comment: Good solution as this will return the hashed URL if DEBUG is set to False. Optionally force the hashed URL like so:

`staticfiles_storage.url(path, force=True)`

Answer (score 11):

Use the default `static` tag:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
static('favicon.ico')
```

There is another tag in `django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles` (as in the accepted answer), but it is deprecated in Django 2.0+.

Comment: Why do I get slash in the beginning? **/static**, even if I never add a slash in the beginning?

Answer (score 9):

@dyve's answer didn't work for me in the development server. Instead I solved it with `find`. Here is the function:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import find
from django.templatetags.static import static

def get_static(path):
    if settings.DEBUG:
        return find(path)
    else:
        return static(path)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get absolute url(including protocol,host and port), you can use `request.build_absolute_uri` function shown as below:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
self.request.build_absolute_uri(staticfiles_storage.url('my-static-image.png'))
# 'http://localhost:8000/static/my-static-image.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

In short words you need to get

- `STATIC_URL`
- `STATIC_ROOT`
- `urlpatterns`
- `staticfiles`
- `templatetags`
- `url parameters`

All in the right place, to get this working. In addition, in real time deployment, circumstances vary, which it is very possible that the current setting you spent 3 hours worked out, works on your local machine but the server.

So I adopted the traditional way!!

```
app
├── static
│   └── json
│       └── data.json
└── views.py
```

`views.py`

```py
import os

with open(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + '/app/static/json/data.json', 'r') as f:
    pass
```