# Static file cannot be found in Django view

Tags: django, static, view, django-settings

I am having an issue with static files in the development server on Django 1.5.4. I am not sure if it is the same problem on the actual production server (running Apache), as I found a solution for that which works at the moment (simply hard coding the full URL - I know it's bad, but it gets the job done).

I am using Reportlab to create a PDF file for my project, and I need to include a picture on that. I followed the answer in a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view):

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
url = static('x.jpg')
```

Unfortunately, the answer I get from the server is an IO Error: 'Cannot open resource "localhost:8000/static/images/x.jpg"', even though a copy and paste of that into the URL bar clearly shows me that the picture is exactly there.

My settings regarding static files are the following, and they do work for everything else (CSS, Javascript, etc):

```
ROOT_PROJECT = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], "..")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PROJECT, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

There are usually a couple of ways to store static files.

1. One way is to create a static folder inside your app folder and store the files there. You can check that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):
2. Is to create a folder and store your static files which are not for any particular app.

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your *settings* file where Django will also look for static files.

For example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

If you are into production then check [production deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/) for more details!

Comment: As I said - it's working perfectly fine with all the other static files - CSS, Javascript etc. They are all in the static folder (in the subfolders js / css) of the main app without any problems whatsoever. Just this image does not load unless I specify the exact address. Something else must be wrong there.