# Django 1.6: How to access static files in view

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721818/django-get-the-static-files-url-in-view) and it didn't work for me. I'm creating a project based off the Heroku "Getting Started" project for Python.

In `views.py`, I'd like to be able to access a file in the `static/data/` folder. However, most of my attempts I make to create the correct url to the file have failed. The only thing that works is putting the absolute path to the file as it exists on my local file system, which obviously won't work when I deploy my app.

Previous attempts to open the file include:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
url = static('data/foobar.csv')
os.path.isfile(url) # False

from django.conf import settings
url = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, 'data/foobar.csv')
os.path.isfile(url) # False
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
/appname
  /app
    /templates
    views.py
  /appname
    /static
      /js
      /css
      /data
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'appname.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appname.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Try with "/static/data/foobar.csv"

Answer (score 19):

Instead of joining the `STATIC_ROOT` with the filename, use the [staticfiles_storage](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/ref/settings.html#staticfiles-storage) interface instead. This will also work with remote static files like S3/django-storages.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

url = staticfiles_storage.url('data/foobar.csv')
```

With `staticfiles_storage` you can also do simple file operations like open, delete, save.

Comment: Hm, for me this points to `/static/...` and breaks both in dev and production. In dev, it works if I use `static/...` without the leading slash. In production (Heroku), the static files are copied to `STATIC_ROOT = staticfiles` and it does not find anything under `static/...`.

Answer (score 14):

The particular staticfiles storage backend you've configured will provide both a `path` method and a `url` method.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
p = staticfiles_storage.path('data/foobar.csv')
content = p.readlines()
# manipulate content
```

The `.url` method returns the same value as Django's static built-in

```
url = static('data/foobar.csv')
```

Answer (score 7):

When you deploy a Django application to Heroku, or when you manually run `manage.py collectstatic` task, all the static assets will be copied to your `STATIC_ROOT` directory. Therefore you should use:

```
file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'data/foobar.csv')
```

Answer (score 5):

`STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'` is your problem. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT), `STATIC_ROOT` is:

> The **absolute** path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.

Currently, you don't even have a path listed there...

Answer (score 3):

Your static files are not at the same place when you are in "dev" or "prod".
In dev, you use the django "runserver" command which will serve your static file with "original" files (eg : `myproject/src/appname/static/appname/images/plop.jpeg`)

In production mode, you must use the "collectstatic" django command which will copy those original file in a "direct public http access folder" (eg : `/static/appname/images/plop.jpeg` for an http access)

But original files are still at the same place (myproject/src/appname/static/appname/images/plop.jpeg), so your view can access those original file directly.

If you know in which app the file your are looking for is, it is very simple. If you want to use the "static overwrite" mecanims of Django, have a look to its functions to get the "final" static file (for exemple, is it `myproject/python-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coolapp/static/coolapp/images/plop.jpeg` or `myproject/src/myapp/static/coolapp/images/plop.jpeg`)

I recommend to read the Django Doc about static finders to better understand how it works : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS

PS : "HTTP path" and "python path" are not the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Don't know if this is the best solution.

In settings.py I created two paths for switching between productive and development. I need to uncomment when deploying the site.

```
#Productive
#STATIC_ROOT = '/home/DimiDev/RESite/static'
#Development
STATIC_ROOT = 'realestate/static'
```

And in my python file, as already stated in this post.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
file_path = staticfiles_storage.path('realestate/ml/2xgBoosting_max.sav')
```

My structure for this file:

```
RESite\realestate\static\realestate\ml\2xgBoosting_max.sav
```

Comment: `path` is more suitable for my usecase than `url` used in other responses.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you what I did, I made an app in which I had to read a CSV file.

 I made the main project directory with ***django-startproject*** command and then made an app. 
In the root I made a folder named static and inside that, I placed the CSV file. 
Now in my views.py 
*read_csv('static/file_name')*

 
All other settings were default and this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved the following way.
First as your settings.py file has this base path:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

You can get files in your static directory this way:

```
url = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/data/foobar.csv')
os.path.isfile(url) # True
```