# Accessing custom directory under static directory in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning Django.
I know how to add use `{% static "abc/xyz" %}` in templates.

But now I want to use something similar in views.py file.

For example `project->my_app->static->resources->abc.json` is the file I need to access in the `views.py` of `my_app`.

When I tried `f = open('resources/abc.json')` it didn't work.

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: you can check for answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879731/django-1-6-how-to-access-static-files-in-view

Comment: Somehow it didn't work.