# How to access static files in django views?

Tags: django, static, django-views

I've some image files that are in the 'img' folder in the static directory of django app. I want to access them all and store into a list in my 'views.py' so that I can iterate through them to display them by rendering them through the template. How can that be done? How to access static files in django views?

Comment: Where are you having problems? Do you know how to list the files in a directory?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to do this, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713009/5985115) could maybe help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return static files passing through a view in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294507/how-to-return-static-files-passing-through-a-view-in-django)