# How to play a sound saved in a known directory with Django, via python script (not template)?

Tags: python, django

I am developing an app in Django.
I have an mp3 file saved in the directory `my_project/static/sounds/1607.mp3`

I have a `script.py` file located in `my_project/my_app/my_folder`
How can I tell my Django to play it at the end of a `script.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok for you to save the mp3 in a model as [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield) ? By this way, you can store the file in the required location using ' upload_to ' too.

And more specific answer to your question:
You can try [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings).
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) module.

This is a (inefficient) way to indicate Django the directory in which is the file you want to play:

```
from playsound import playsound
import os    
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

result = finders.find('static/sounds/1607.mp3')
searched_locations = finders.searched_locations
sound_dir = os.path.join(searched_locations[0]+r'\sounds\1607.mp3')

playsound(sound_dir)

print("Sound just played!")
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738606/9733868) if you are looking for including your static files inside your code.