# django.contrib.sites.models.Site gives example.com as the server url

Tags: python, django, django-sites

I want to get the server url in django. So I went through stackoverflow and found out that in order to do this I will have to do the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> mysite = Site.objects.get_current()
```

I tried the above inside `python manage.py shell` in the production server and expected mysite to give me the production server's url but it gives example.com

```
>>> mysite
<Site: example.com>
```

Am I missing some configuration or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) - see [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

Answer (score 9):

The `Site` object is stored in the database. Change it there, and you're done.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
mysite = Site.objects.get_current()
mysite.domain = 'mysite.com'
mysite.name = 'My Site'
mysite.save()
```

Alternatively, you can change it in the `/admin/` section of your site at `/admin/sites/site/1/`.

This allows you to [run multiple sites from the same code-base](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/).