# Django how to specify a base url

Tags: html, django

So there should be a very basic way to do this, but unfortunately I don't seem to be able to find it.

How can one set an Href link to point to the 'base website url' + the 'link', rather than adding the link to the current page.

I.e. if I'm at www.example.com/content1/

I want the search function to go to www.example.com/search/

and not www.example.com/content1/search

I could just specify "www.example.com/search/" but then if it page is deployed locally I end up with a bunch of links to non-existent pages or vice versa. How can I specify the The Base hosting URL using DJango (whichever the server is running, whether the hostname, the current server ip, localhost etc.).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django/

Comment: also this might help: https://github.com/lalzada/django-baseurl

Comment: I did <a target="_blank" href=" /post/{{ post.slug }}">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is the [name your urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and then use the  [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). Example below:

First, name your views. Use something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^search/$', views.search_view, name="search"),
    ...
]
```

In this example, you've got your url for your `example.com/search/` view. It is named 'search', which can be used `url` template tags and using the `reverse()` function.

Next, in your template, use the `url` tag with your url name:

```
<a href="{% url 'search' %}">Search</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate the string "{% url 'search' %}" with some other string, just in the template?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to add 'base website url' to your href, it is implied. Make sure href is prefixed with '/' to set and absolute path and no '/' for relative.

```
 <a href="/">home</a>
```

is the same as

```
 <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/">home</a>
```

and will work no matter which sub directory you are in

If you are on the homepage and you use the link:

```
<a href="sample">sample</a>
```

it will effectively equal:

```
 <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/sample">sample</a>
```

but that same link used on the page http://www.mywebsite.com/sample will equate to:

```
 <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/sample/sample">sample</a>
```

using:

```
<a href="/sample">sample</a>
```

Will always equate to the following no matter where on the site it is used:

```
 <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/sample">sample</a>
```

If you are using django consider using the url template tag as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457661/alex) suggested:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1):

Make the link point to `/search`.

Any link that starts with `/` is relative to the domain root (say, `http://example.com/`) whereas any other relative link is relative to the current URL.