# NoReverseMatch error using get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-urls

I am trying to use get_absolute_url to follow DRY rules. If I code the class to build the href directly from the slug it all works fine. Ugly, messy but working...

So I am trying to get this done right using get_absolute_url() and I am getting stuck with a NoReverseMatch exception using the code below. I know this must be some kind of newbie error, but I have been up and down all the docs and forums for days, and still can't figure this one out!

I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /calendar
Reverse for 'pEventsCalendarDetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Test-12014-05-05'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'pEventsCalendarDetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Test-12014-05-05'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 429
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

using the following models.py excerpt:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Event(models.Model):
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    eventDescription = models.TextField()
    eventDate = models.DateField()
    eventTime = models.TimeField()
    eventLocation = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    eventURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.eventName + str(instance.eventDate),
                         unique_with=['eventDate'],
                         slugify=lambda value: value.replace(' ','-'))

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        path = reverse('pEventsCalendarDetail', (), kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
        return "http://%s" % (path)
```

The complete urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^calendar$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.calendar', name='calendar'),
    url(r'^forum$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.forum', name='forum'),
    url(r'^donate$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.donate', name='donate'),
    url(r'^donate_thanks$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.donate_thanks', name='donate_thanks'),
    url(r'^what_is_fll$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.what_is_fll', name='what_is_fll'),
    url(r'^core_values$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.core_values', name='core_values'),
    url(r'^follow_the_phoenix$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.follow_the_phoenix', name='follow_the_phoenix'),
    url(r'^followEnter/$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.followEnter', name='followEnter'),
    url(r'^followList/$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.followList', name='followList'),
    url(r'^about_us$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.about_us', name='about_us'),
    url(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'phoenixEvents.views.calendarDetail', name='pEventsCalendarDetail'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second positional argument to [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is `urlconf` argument:

```
reverse(viewname[, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None])
```

To make it work use keyword argument for setting `args`:

```
path = reverse('pEventsCalendarDetail', args=(), kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

Or, don't set `args` at all:

```
path = reverse('pEventsCalendarDetail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

Comment: Thank you!!
I thought the name provided the reference to the urlconf info. Isn't that what I am specifying in the urls.py file? Wouldn't adding that into a call to reverse() be imbedding the url into another place in the code...
That only leaves me with the missing 'domain' portion of the url. Is there should I get that from os.path or is there a more Django-ish way to get that?

Comment: @Arana did it help? Django finds your `urls.py` files automatically, no need to specify `urlconf` argument manually. Unless you are doing smth "outside of the box".

Comment: Yes, it certainly did! Sorry, I wasn't clearer about that. What I have now is missing the domain (<a href="http:///calendarDetail/Test-12014-05-05/">Test 1</a>) What is best way to add that last portion?

Comment: I know it finds my urls.py automatically, that is why I was questioning the 'need' for a parameter in reverse() that would specify urlconf. Is it a leftover from an older version, or is there another reason I would want to use it? (Just trying to learn more...)

Comment: @Arana Ok, thanks, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django.

Comment: @Arana you would use `urlconf` argument when your `urls` are defined in a custom place, not in `urls.py`, for example. It is just a hint for Django to reverse based on the specified path to the custom `urls.py`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Alec. I'll read that post again. Now I should be able to make more sense out of it!

Comment: One final comment for anyone that is looking for the FINAL answer on how to build the full url. I did cheat a bit by adding the port number to the initial domain name, but once I'm on a production server the port number will be the default port 80.

    def get_absolute_url(self):
  from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
  path = reverse('pEventsCalendarDetail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
  return "http://%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, path)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use both the `permalink` decorator *and* the `reverse()` call. They both do the same thing. Drop the decorator: it is deprecated.