# Display full Image URL on JSON output using Django Tastypie

Tags: json, django, django-models, tastypie

I have created a json API which can be found [HERE](http://178.62.67.237/api/v1/residential/?format=json)

The problem I have is that the Image URL is not displayed fully.
For example the currect output is :

image: "/media/images/ShanRoberts_NWales_Vitocal300A_xgGCGrG.JPG",

I need it to be displayed like :

image: "http://178.62.67.237/media/images/ShanRoberts_NWales_Vitocal300A_xgGCGrG.JPG",

Any ideas?

Comment: You might be looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2345954/1924026

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static` and `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri` to get the full URL.

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.http.HttpRequest import build_absolute_uri

relative_url = static('x.jpg')
# url now contains '/static/x.jpg', assuming a static path of '/static/'
absolute_url = build_absolute_uri(relative_url)
```

Comment: Do I add this to my models.py? Sorry but I have never worked on URLS!

Comment: I guess that you can add this to your model, but better not to save it in your database in case you change static folder or your DNS or ip ! You can use just build_absolute_uri in your case!

Comment: What about the import which is called 'request'? Wat do I have to pip install in order to make use of it?

Comment: my bad, it is HttpRequest

Comment: I am getting an Import Error--> ImportError: No module named HttpRequest

Comment: This document explains the APIs for HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects, which are defined in the django.http module. here is the doc mate: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#module-django.http