# How to generate absolute urls in Django 2 templates

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I have an html template, which is used to render an email, in that template, I want to attach verification links.

I am using the following code to generate the link

```
{% url 'verify_email' token=token email=email %}
```

but this one generates following URL instead of absolute URL.

[image]

I read this SO thread

- [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

and some initial google results but all of them seems old and not working for me.

**TLDR:** How do I generate absolute URLs in Django2 template files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `build_absolute_uri()` referenced in the other thread and register a custom template tag. Request is supplied in the context (that you enable via `takes_context`) as long as you have `django.template.context_processors.request` included in your templates context processors.

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def absolute_url(context, view_name, *args, **kwargs):
    request = context['request']
    return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs))
```

More on where and how to do that [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Then you can use the tag in your template like this:

```
{% absolute_url 'verify_email' token=token email=email %}
```

Comment: `Unsolved reverence 'context'` error for this line of code: `equest = context['request']`
How to fix this?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/ for the code example with `takes_context=True`.