# Django Absolute url

Tags: python, django, codeigniter, url

So I am new to django I have been working on PHP CodeIgniter in which to put absolute URL in href I used a function called `base_url` by calling URL helper

```
<?php echo base_url().'user/login';?>
```

which gives output something like

`http://localhost/projectname/user/login`
I want the same thing in Django but haven't got any answer or answer which I could understand. I don't want to use relative URL and my expected result is should be something like this

```
{% url 'login' %}
```

above code should return 
`http://localhost/projectname/user/login`

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Comment: if you're going to serve all your project urls under `/projectname/` you need to tell Django that by adding it to your root urls. Or you need to setup your server to remove it from the path when proxying to your django app server. But then you have to add it manually when you build your absolute uri. I think the first method is preferred. So then you can just use relative urls.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django - use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get absolute url in 2 ways in django.

One is build your custom template tag by using 
`HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri()` method from HttpRequest

Or simply use following line in your django template.

```
<a href="{{ request.get_host }}{% url your_url_name %}">Link</a>
```

See this link for details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

Comment: will it work if i put my project in subfolder of any project on server eg. from  https://domainname.com/   to  https://domainname.com/xyz_folder ?

Comment: @dvijparekh yes it should do the trick as per django Official doc. See this 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

Answer (score 1):

If you have a URL path in your **urls.py** file defined like this:

```
path('user/', views.user, name='user_list')
```

Then you can call this URL in the template like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'user_list' %}">Users</a>
```

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url for details.

For absolute URL you can use:

```
<a href="{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'user_list' %}">Users</a>
```

Comment: i want to show absolute url when it renders html but above code only shows relative url

Comment: In that case, you can use `<a href="{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'user_list' %}">Users</a>`