# localhost in build_absolute_uri for Django with Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx

On production I use the chain Django - UWSGI - Docker - Nxing. UWSGI works with the port 50012 and Ngxin is configured as:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:50012;
```

Django process thinks that its host is `localhost:50012` instead of the domain that Nginx listens to. So when the function `build_absolute_uri` is called there's `localhost:50012` instead of my domain. Is there a way to make Django use the custom host name when `build_absolute_uri` is called?

**Notice**: in some libraries `build_absolute_uri` called implicitly (like `social-django`, or example), so avoiding this function is not a solution in my case.

Comment: I guess you want to take a look at the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/). Are you sure none of the answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django) would apply here?

Comment: @PauloScardine How is it supposed to help? In the documentation, it's said, this framework should be used in case of several domains and for associating objects with each of them. In my case I don't care of any objects and I have exactly one domain.

Comment: Specifically ["Getting the current domain for full URLs"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls) on that page.

Comment: @PauloScardine I do not think it relates to what I asked about...

Comment: Set `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` in settings and configure nginx to pass the header along. Otherwise django will use `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` or `request.META['SERVER_NAME']`. The nginx part of the setup probably is best suited to another site in the network as it is more about infrastructure management than about programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The problem

When the public hostname you use to reach the proxy differ from the internal hostname of the application server, Django has no way to know which hostname was used in the original request unless the proxy is passing this information along.

## Possible Solutions

### 1) Set the proxy to pass along the orginal host

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host):

> The X-Forwarded-Host (XFH) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
>
> Host names and ports of reverse proxies (load balancers, CDNs) may differ from the origin server handling the request, in that case the X-Forwarded-Host header is useful to determine which Host was originally used.

There are two things you should do:

1. ensure all proxies in front of Django are passing along the `X-Forwarded-Host` header
2. turn on `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` in the settings
3. if the internal and external scheme differ as well, set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` to a meaningful value and set the server to send the corresponding header

When `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` is set to `True` in `settings.py`,  `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri` uses the `X-Forwarded-Host` header instead of `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` or `request.META['SERVER_NAME']`.

I will not delve too much into the proxy setup part (as it is more related to professional network administration than to programming in the scope of this site) but for nginx it should be something like:

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    ...
    proxy_pass http://upstream:port;
}
```

Probably the best solution as it is fully dynamic, you don't have to change anything if the public scheme/hostname changes in the future.

If the internal and external scheme differ as well you may want to set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` in `settings.py` to something like this:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

And then add the following to the server config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

### 2) Use the same hostname for public and private servers

Lets say your public hostname is "host.example.com": you can add a line like this to your `/etc/hosts` (on Windows `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`):

```
127.0.0.1    host.example.com
```

Now you can use the hostname in the nginx config:

```
proxy_pass http://host.example.com:port;
```

When the internal and external scheme differ as well (external https, internal http), you may want to set `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` as described in the first solution.

Every time the public hostname changes you will have to update the config but I guess this is OK for small projects.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well in my case! One optional thing I would add to your answer would be `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` if needed.

Comment: Answer updated with recommended `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` setting for when internal and external schemes are also different.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine working using `proxy_redirect`

Lets say you have a `container` or an `upstream` with the name `app` and you want it to return `127.0.0.1` as the host, Then your config should include:

```yaml
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:8000;

    proxy_redirect http://app:8000 http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

Here's my final config:

```yaml
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:8000;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect http://app:8000 http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

Also checkout this article for a detailed explanation https://mattsegal.dev/nginx-django-reverse-proxy-config.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem same as the question, I used nginx, gunicorn and django on production without docker.

```
get_current_site(request).domain
```

returned `localhost` so I have some issue in drf yasg base url. Simply I solved it by adding

```
include proxy_params;
```

to nginx conf.