# django filefield returning localhost-prefixed URL

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying not to specify the full path of the web app in the settings to make it as portable as possible.

However,

with `MEDIA_URL="/media/"`, an URL returned from a Django FileField model is **http://localhost/media/...**.

with `MEDIA_URL="//example.com/media/"`, the URL returned is **http://example.com/media/...**.

But the schema (http/s) and domain (example.com) should match those of the requesting page. How can I do this?

The Django app is served through Nginx in combination with Gunicorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like nginx and Django are not configured to pass and use http host name (e.g. X-Forwarded-Host header). This looks like a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044808/6865