# Can't get Django's get_absolute_url to set up the link properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to use the get_absolute_url function in one of my templates like so:

**template.html**

```
<div class="card-columns">
    {% for category in main_categories %}
    <div onclick="document.location = {{ category.get_absolute_url }};" class="card">
```

I'm fairly new to programming in general so I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it, but I have been able to get it to return a couple views individually by using if statements like this:

**models.py**

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.pk == 1:
            return reverse('forum:index')
        if self.pk == 2:
            return reverse('tutorials:cybertips')
        return reverse('tutorials:subjects', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

I don't get any errors, and when clicking on the cards with pk=1 & pk=2 it returns the correct url pattern. The other cards loads fine but don't link to anything. When inspecting the html it looks like it returns a url so I'm wondering if i'm not understanding the onclick function? Here are my urls(in this app):

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'tutorials'
url_patterns = [
    path('category/<int:pk>/', views.SubjectView.as_view(), name='subjects'),
    path('cybertips/', views.cybertips, name='cybertips'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class MainCategoriesView(ListView):
    model = MainCategory
    context_object_name = 'main_categories'

class SubjectView(ListView):
    model = Subject
    context_object_name = 'subjects'
```

Any help is appreciated. Or if there is a more efficient and safe way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will check it out more today. I think I just need to read some more documentation =)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting rid of the `onclick="document.location"` stuff and just wrapped the `<div>` in a `a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">` and the links work just fine.