# Recover active site domain in settings, since I have multisites

Tags: django

I have a problem that is recovering the domain of the site that is currently active, I need to recover it in settings to pass a configuration of a project that I am doing and since I can not use

`from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site`

or something like settings, is there any way to get the domain here?

Comment: Just so that I understand your question, you have a domain e.g mydomain.com that is currently pointing to a Django project and you want to remap it to another project?

Comment: In case I own 2 website, www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com, I needed to add the website domain that would be active in a variable in the settings

Comment: What do you mean, add the domain that would be active? Will both domains be pointing to the app?

Comment: I don't know if it would be possible, but something like get_current_site()

Comment: I think this is the way to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817935/6802978

Comment: but you can't use this method in setting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

> In order to serve different sites in production, you’d create a separate settings >file with each SITE_ID (perhaps importing from a common settings file to avoid >duplicating shared settings) and then specify the appropriate >DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for each site.