# Django: Correct "url" tag for use in emails? (A complete "http://..." tag.)

Tags: django

I naively used the `{% url` tag in an email body, only to discover that it didn't include the site-name.

What should I do to create a hyperlink, for use in an email body, that *does* include the proper site-name?

- Instead of `/foo/bar` ... which is the string that the tag returns ...
- I want: `h-t-t-p-s://mysite.com/foo/bar`  *(you know what I meant!)*

... without having to hard-code the site-name as a literal in the template as in `https://somewhere.com{% url ...`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been answered here: [How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18396895/13168118

```
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('view_name', args=(obj.pk, )))
```