# Get full request URL from inside APIView in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a method, or an attribute in request object that I can access to return me the URL exactly as the client requested? With the query params included?

I've checked `request.build_absolute_uri` after looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django) but it just returns the URL without the query params.

I need the URL because my API response returns the URL for the "next page" of results. I could build it from the `query_params` attributes, but this view takes a lot of query params and some exclude others, so having access to the request url would save me a lot of pain.

Comment: You want `request.get_full_path()`

Comment: YES! Thank you. Do you mind submitting as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get full path, including query string, you want `request.get_full_path()`

Comment: This also works in serializer's `create()` as `self.context['request'].get_full_path()`