# Django displaying images from media file instead of database

Tags: python, django

How do I display images from **media file** instead of database? Specifically I want it to load images uploaded by users from `media_cdn`. I feel like only the **views.py** require changes but I'm not sure if other areas should be changed as well.

Here are my Django codes

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media_cdn')
```

**views.py**

```
def imgdownload(request):
    allimages = ImagefieldModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/show.html',{'images': allimages})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    ....
    path("show/", views.imgdownload, name="imgdownload"),
    .... ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class ImagefieldModel(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "media")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "imageupload"
```

**show.html**

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}

{% load static %}
 

 {% block content %}
      <head>
        <title>Django Display Images</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="container">
          <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {% for img in images %}  
                <tr>
                  <td>{{img.title}}</td>
                  <td><img src="/{{ BASIC_DIR }}/{{img.img}}" width="120"/></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %} 
              </tbody>
          </table>  
          </div>
      </body>
 {% endblock %}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can to use "url": `{{ ìmg.img.url }}`. Or `get_absolute_url` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django

Answer (score 1):

You can to use "url": `{{ ìmg.img.url }}`, in your example, to change for this:

```
<td><img src="{{ img.img.url }}" width="120"/></td>
```

> All that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative to MEDIA_ROOT). You’ll most likely want to use the convenience url attribute provided by Django. For example, if your ImageField is called mug_shot, you can get the absolute path to your image in a template with {{ object.mug_shot.url }}.

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields)

Comment: alright will try it out soon. Will get back to you on the result tmr

Comment: nope did not work. Maybe the changes should be in view.py since since the "ImagefieldModel.objects.all()" is getting the file path from database

Comment: `<td><img src="/{{ BASIC_DIR }}/{{img.img}}" width="120"/></td>` to change for this `<td><img src="{{ img.img.url }}" width="120"/></td>`