# Why is image serializer feild not returning link format

Tags: python, reactjs, django, image, django-rest-framework

Is there any update on image field serializer? I was trying to server an image api to the frontend. My serializer is not returning image link instead its returning the path relative to the base dir of the django-project

**models.py**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'profiles/{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
```

**serializer**

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ['image']
```

**serializer.data result **

```
[
    {
        "image": "/media/profiles/quiz-app-.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "/media/profiles/coding2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "/media/profiles/dummy_2s9CyV8.jpg"
    }
]
```

instead of the above result I want something like a link in return

```
[
    {
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media/profiles/quiz-app-.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media/profiles/coding2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media/profiles/dummy_2s9CyV8.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django

Answer (score 0):

You can check for details

[How can I get the full/absolute URL (with domain) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345708/how-can-i-get-the-full-absolute-url-with-domain-in-django)

Using following project can help to solve this problem using external file stores and CDNs for better performance in future.

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/