# Calling api without knowing ip address in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-modeladmin

I have a post request

```
http://localhost:8000/api/orders/shipment
```

what i want to do is i dont want to pass domain/ip address and access the api something like Django admin console give "172.18.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2017 14:30:29] "POST **/adminorder/order/import/** HTTP/1.1" 200 "

I searched in the django documentation get_absolute_url() method is there to define custom urls, I am not getting how to use this in this scenario.

Comment: Post the code in which you call the POST request.

Comment: I am using this url to import the csv dataset  **data = requests.post(url=url, data=content, headers = headers)** i am passing it as url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the server name in Django for a complete url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892997/how-do-i-get-the-server-name-in-django-for-a-complete-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's impossible to use a relative url in requests, but you can get around this by creating a function which prepends the relevant domain to your url. (Make sure to import your settings file!)

```
from django.conf import settings

development_url = "http://localhost:8000/"
production_url = "http://myapisite.com/"

def create_url(relative_url):
    # If you are on your development server. This is assuming your development always has DEBUG = True, and your production is always DEBUG = False
    if settings.DEBUG:
        return development_url + relative_url

    # Production
    return production_url + relative_url
```

Therefore `print(create_url("api/test/anothertest"))` will return `http://localhost:8000/api/test/anothertest`.

And this is how you would use it:

```
url = create_url("api/orders/shipment/")
data = requests.post(url=url, data=content, headers = headers)
```